# MongoDB Distinct with condition in Java

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, distinct

Is there any possibility to implement MongoDB distinct with condition, like this below, but with Java driver?

```
db.orders.distinct( 'ord_dt', { price: { $gt: 10 } } )
```

I have tried with `MongoRepository`, like below

```
// Enables the distinct flag for the query
List<Person> findDistinctPeopleByLastnameOrFirstname(String lastname, String firstname);

List<Person> findPeopleDistinctByLastnameOrFirstname(String lastname, String firstname);
```

But in my opinion it is not working correctly. I have also tried `MongoTemplate`

```
mongoTemplate.getCollection("mycollection").distinct("myfield")
```

But there is no way to implement condition. Any idea how to solve that?

Best regards

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Spring `MongoTemplate` has inbuilt support for `distinct` with `query`:

`mongoTemplate.getCollection("collection_name").distinct("field", new BasicDBObject("price", new BasicDBObject("$gt", 10)));`

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
BasicDBObject match = new BasicDBObject();
match.put("$query", new BasicDBObject("price", new BasicDBObject("$gt", 10)));
List list = mongoTemplate.getCollection("mycollection").distinct("ord_dt", match);
```

Comment: OK, Thanks. Another question is, how to combine it with Pageable interface to provide paging results ?

Comment: You may use this [link]( http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html)